# How to keep sharepoint:popoutmenu open

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, controls, popupmenu

I am implementing a checklist within a SharePoint popout menu. I want to enable users to choose multiple choices within the `checkboxlist`, hence I want the checklist to stay open when the user is selecting the choices, and close when he clicks a particular button.

I have tried using `StayOpen` property, but it doesn't work.

Below is the partial UI code of my popoutmenu control:

```
<Sharepoint:PopoutMenu runat="server" ID="CustomiseTabs" isCheckable="true" 
    StayOpen="true" AnchorCss="commentsAnchor" Visible="false" 
    IconUrl="~/_layouts/1033/IMAGES/CSI/Drop-down.png" >
  <asp:UpdatePanel  ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <div align="left" >
        <asp:CheckBoxList  ID="cbHideTabs" runat="server"  isCheckable="true">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
      </div>
```

I haven't been able to find any event, property or attribute that keeps the menu in open state.

Any pointers will be helpful...

Comment: Hi Nandini, your question will get better attention if you include the relevant code you're working with to show what you've tried. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find a way to work around popoutmenu,so I used Ajax Control toolkits popupextender,which worked the way i wanted